# Java array pass without reference

Tags: java, arrays, reference

I am trying to pass an array without using a reference, but directly with the values :

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
            int[] result = insertionSort({10,3,4,12,2});
    }

    public static int[] insertionSort(int[] arr){
        return arr;
    }
```

but it returns the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
```

When I try the following code , it works , can anybody please explain the reason ?

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = {10,3,4,12,2};
        int[] result = insertionSort(arr);  
    }

    public static int[] insertionSort(int[] arr){
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: An important note: Java **never** passes by reference, only by value.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by value not by reference ? because when I pass an array to a method which manipulates values of this array , values of the original array change too .
Therefor , sometime I need to clone an array if I don't want the original array to be changed !

Comment: Try to receive an array in a method and initialize the array inside the method (`new int[20]` or similar will do), then pass a null array to the method and print the array outside the method, it will still be `null`, that's because Java passes by value, not the reference of the object.

Answer (score 10):

It has to be

```
int[] result = insertionSort(new int[]{10,3,4,12,2});
```

`{10,3,4,12,2}` is a syntactic sugar for array initialization, which must go with the declaration statement like the one in the following -

```
int[] arr = {10,3,4,12,2};
```

Something as follows is not allowed too -

```
int[] arr; // already declared here but not initialized yet
arr = {10,3,4,12,2}; // not a declaration statement so not allowed
```

Answer (score 5):

```
insertionSort({10,3,4,12,2})
```

is not valid java because you don't specify a **type** in your method call.
The JVM does not know what type of array this is. Is it an array with double values or with int values?

What you can do is `insertionSort(new int[]{10, 3 ,4 12, 2});`

Answer (score 1):

`int[] array = { a, b, ...., n }` is a shorthand initialization - you have to write:

```
int[] result = insertionSort(new int[]{10,3,4,12,2});
```

to initialize it anonymously.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing much to add to what others said.

However I believe the reason why you should use `new int[]{10,3,4,12,2}` (like others stated) and Java doesn't let you use just `{10,3,4,12,2}` is that Java is strong typed.

If you just use `{10,3,4,12,2}` there is no clue of what the type of the array elements can be. They seem to be integers, but they can be `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, etc...

Well, actually it might infer the type from the method signature, and fire a compile error if it doesn't fit, but it seems complicated.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that Java would have no clue on guessing the elements type.